# Setting autoWebview: ' true' at protractor config.js file causing machine logout, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, protractor, appium

Setting autoWebview: ' true' at protractor config file causing system logout, ubuntu 16.4

This is my config file:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',

    specs: ['demo.js'],

    capabilities: {
        platformName : 'android',
        platformVersion : '4.4.2',
        deviceName: 'PNV4PN4LUORWSCRO',
        directConnect: true,
        browserName: "android",
        autoWebview: ' true',

        app: '/path/abc.apk',
        appPackage: 'xyz',
        appActivity: '.MainActivity',
           newCommandTimeout: 140,
        autoWebviewTimeout: 10000,
        fulReset: true
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000',
    allScriptsTimeout: 22000,

    onPrepare: function () {
        var wd = require('wd'),
            protractor = require('protractor'),
            wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(protractor, wd);
        wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);
    }
};
```

If I am not setting autoWebview: ' true', then I am getting below issue:

```
[21:38:48] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4723     /wd/hub  
[21:38:48] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:39:04] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.  
         E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html  
        at WebDriverError (/home/dilip/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:27:5)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/dilip/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:580:13)
        at /home/dilip/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:360:15
        at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/home/dilip/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/home/dilip/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/home/dilip/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)
        at asyncRun (/home/dilip/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2652:27)
        at /home/dilip/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    [15:01:09] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

And below is **spec.js** file content:

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() { var firstNumber =element(by.model('xyz:id/data.email')); var secondNumber = element(by.model('xyz:id/data.password')); it('Open login page', function() { firstNumber.sendKeys("dilip"); secondNumber.sendKeys(7668); 
});
```

Please, somebody help me out.

Comment: could you please separate out the two cases(with and without `autoWebView`) with details.

Comment: I mean to say that when i put "autoWebview: ' true'," at my config.js file for protractor and run this file, my system logout during the execution of the script.

Comment: This is my "demo_spec.js" file content: 

 describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
var firstNumber =element(by.model('xyz:id/data.email'));
var secondNumber = element(by.model('xyz:id/data.password'));

 it('Open login page', function() {
    firstNumber.sendKeys("dilip");
    secondNumber.sendKeys(7668);

 //   expect(firstNumber.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('arshdeep.singh@nextgen$

    //expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://localhost:8080/nextgen-ap$
 });
});

Comment: please put this block of code in the question itself, and system logout means your machine on which you are operating or the android device?

Comment: my machine(operating system 16.04), thats why i am totally blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As described in [appium#6526](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6526), there is an issue, if a new version of procps and old version of an appium-chromedriver are used. Unfortunately, if I install appium, then I get old version of appium-chromedriver@2.8.3, because of appium's [npm-shrinkwrap.json](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/v1.5.2/npm-shrinkwrap.json) (which is removed in [master](https://github.com/appium/appium/pull/6259)).

I'm not npm expert, but solution, which satisfied me is:

1. Add appium to devDependencies and scripts in package.json

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
     "appium": "^1.5.2",
     ...
   },
   "scripts": {
     "appium": "appium"
   }
   ```

   This allow you to run app-local version of appium with

   ```
   npm run appium
   ```

   instead of global appium installation.
2. Add npm-shrinkwrap.json (or generate with `npm shrinkwrap --dev` and edit) file to overwrite dependency:

   ```
   {
     "name": "my app",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "dependencies": {
       "appium": {
         "version": "1.5.2",
         "from": "appium@>=1.5.2 <2.0.0",
         "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/appium/-/appium-1.5.2.tgz",
         "dependencies": {
           "appium-android-driver": {
             "version": "1.10.7",
             "from": "appium-android-driver@1.10.7",
             "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/appium-android-driver/-/appium-android-driver-1.10.7.tgz"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Then install and run appium with

   ```
   npm install
   npm run appium
   ```

If I don't missing anything, then it should do the trick. Maybe in next appium release you don't need npm-shrinkwrap.json anymore.

**EDIT:** Example: [ionic-appium-protractor-example](https://github.com/Bessonov/ionic-appium-protractor-example)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is only seen on `Ubuntu 16.04` because i had installed other version of Ubuntu i.e, 14.04 and this issue is not found on that version.